# Probability and Statistics using chess game board

Tags: probability, statistics

There are 18,000 adults who belong to a nationwide chess club. Among the 18,000 adults, 8,000
prefer to play with white(W), whereas the rest prefer black(B). Among all members, 11,000 prefer
to play chess on the computer(C), the others prefer the regular board(RB). 3,000 members prefer
to play with white on the computer. Suppose an adult club member is selected at random.

(a) Find the probability that the person prefers to play with black. That is, find P(B).

(b) Find the probability that the person prefers to play with black on the regular board. That
is, find P(B ∩ RB).

(c) Find the probability that the person prefers the black pieces, given that the person prefers
to play on the regular board. That is, find P(B|RB).

(d) Are the two events “the person prefers black” and “the person prefers the regular board”
mutually exclusive? Are they independent? Give supporting calculations.

Can anyone help me solve this question.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Comment: You've shown no effort to answer the question. Venn Diagrams might help clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this can help you get started
$$P(B)=\frac{\mbox{prefer to play black}}{\mbox{total chess club members}}$$
$$P(RB)=\frac{\mbox{prefer the regular board}}{\mbox{total chess club members}}$$
Study [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability?wprov=sfla1) to figure out the rest. Let me know if you have any questions.